# The brick is falling away from the rest of the house, how do I fix this the right way?

Tags: walls, brick, gap, rodent

I bought this house and I noticed this gap in the wall outside. Looks like the previous owner has tried to fix it in the past with foam and other materials.

There's a squirrel coming into the attic from here too. I'd like to fix this the right way. What do I need to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: looks like a rainscreen gap

Comment: If that is expanding foam in there....it made the problem worse.

Answer (score 2):

Nonstructural brick like yours gets installed with a gap between it and the wall. There are little ties back in there that fix the brick parallel to the wood wall. There should be drainage for the gap at the base of the wall. Searching the internet for `brick wythe wood wall assembly drainage` I found https://www.gobrick.com/media/file/28-brick-veneer-wood-stud-walls.pdf which looks like a nice tutorial for a homeowner with nonstructural brick.

After confirming that your wall has functioning drainage along its base, remove that spray foam, buy and install some backer rod that fits snug in your gap, and caulk that opening with an exterior rated sealant.